# Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in prefix operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I make my first step in js and doing a tutorial for a CRUD app with node and react I have the next error and I don't know why. Find in internet and nothing. Thanks!

```
./src/App.js
  Line 1:  Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in prefix operation

> 1 | --- a/src/App.js
    |   ^
  2 | +++ b/src/App.js
  3 | @@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
  4 |  import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
```

and this is the code of App.js

```
--- a/src/App.js
+++ b/src/App.js
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
+import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
+import { ImplicitCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
 import {
   CssBaseline,
   withStyles,
@@ -21,7 +23,8 @@ const App = ({ classes }) => (
     <CssBaseline />
     <AppHeader />
     <main className={classes.main}>
-      <Home />
+      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
+      <Route path="/implicit/callback" component={ImplicitCallback} />
     </main>
   </Fragment>
 );
```

Comment: Looks like you have the `{` in the wrong place, try placing after the import..

Comment: Please add your code (app.js)

Comment: It is a code with merge conflict.